# Is it possible to retrieve Facebook Page's created time/date?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-page

The information obtained from http://graph.facebook.com/page_id provides the basic information about the Page but it does not include any information about the created_time of the Facebook Page.

Is it possible to obtain this information if an access token to manage pages is retrieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no such field retrievable in the API but if the page has Timeline enabled they may have added a 'founded' date or similar as a milestone, which may be of use depending on what you're doing